# Switched compiler - performance dropped - Trying to understand why

Tags: c, performance, compilation

I'm writing a Ruby C Extension that computes the "soft selection" of a set of vertices. It's many iteration where the distance between 3d points are computed.

Initially I used Pelles C IDE - based it on a template I had found.

I then made an update, where I switched to using `nmake` that comes with Visual Studio C++ Express 2010. What I found was a performance drop - which was odd because if anything it should have been faster.

I then reverted back to the original code I had written in Pelles C and compiled it with `nmake` and found that the exact same code was slower.

**Pelles C**

```
> Updating soft selection took 0.741 seconds (12176 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.751 seconds (10911 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.859 seconds (10765 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.753 seconds (10653 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.75 seconds (10747 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.751 seconds (10822 of 21692 Vertices)
```

**Visual Studio**

```
> Updating soft selection took 1.282 seconds (11853 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 1.273 seconds (12204 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 1.286 seconds (11720 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 1.248 seconds (12996 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 1.293 seconds (10705 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 1.276 seconds (12204 of 21692 Vertices)
```

I'm very inexperienced with C and compiling - but I assume that the performance difference is due to differences between the compiler and the compile instructions?

For the `nmake` version I used the Makefile produced by `extconf.rb` - for the Pelles C version I used whatever the setting was for the sample project I found.

Am I right in that it's the `CFLAGS` that's important here?

**CFLAGS?**

For the Pelles C project is is:
`CCFLAGS = -Tx86-coff -MD -Ot -Ox -W1 -Gd -Ze -Zl#`

For the `nmake` project it is:
`CFLAGS   =  -MD -Zi -O2b2xg- -G6`

When I looked up `CFLAGS` and performance it usually mentioned the flags `O`, `O2` and `O3` - now I see an `O2` in the `nmake` Makefile, but with an odd set of trailing characters.

The Pelles C project has `Ot` and `Ox` ... ?

I was unable to work out the meaning of these. The extension will be compiled under Windows and OSX (PPC and Intel). What configuration of the compiler can I do to get the most performance out of it? At least restore the performance I had.

**Makefile and Pelles C configuration**

Here is a Pastie of the `nmake` Makefile: http://pastie.org/3543595

Here is a Pastie of the Pelles C project file: http://pastie.org/3543597

Comment: The problem with the Microsoft C++ compiler is that it might not be compiling your program down into machine code but rather into the CLR (Common Language Runtime) which is then "interpreted" (I know it's a politcally charged word) in a way much like java Bytecodes are interpreted. This could explain the differences - because there is an overhead of starting the CLR every time you run the program. (I"m not sure how you force the compiler to compile into native machine code - but I think it can be done for C and C++)

Comment: Perhaps Pelles just compiles your code better.

Comment: @Zeke That's pretty unlikely. You have to take extra steps to get C++/CLI.

Comment: @Zeke: 1. Unlikely to be true by default. 2. Unlikely to explain that big of a difference in performance.

Comment: @Jason (and David) - haven't played with Visual C++ or .NET for a while but my first experience with it was that I was trying to make a console based program that was standalone in one single .exe file. The "default" settings (at least when using the GUI IDE to create a project) was to create a CLR program that needed the runtime libraries to work.

Comment: And part of my first comment still stands - even if the issue isn't CLR - it is a case of Visual C++ programs requiring more overhead than the Pelles C compiler.

Comment: Mind you, I did not use the Visual Studio IDE nor C++. I used plain C and the `nmake` utility. (Does it use the same compiler as Visual Studio C++?)

Comment: @Zeke Hansell: I'll make the same comment I made before. I doubt the "overhead" makes that big of a performance difference.

Comment: @Jason - you can doubt all you want, I'm just trying to offer some suggestions as to what is causing the difference in performance. I would suggest that the size of the compiled programs of each compiler be compared. Quite likely, the Pelles C compiler is designed for writing non-gui apps, and therefore it doesn't have libraries (or hooks for connecting to such libraries) to handle the windowing and GUI issues. That fact alone could make the output of Pelles C compiler quicker to load into memory and to start running.

Comment: `nmake`'s output was a 8KB files, while the original Pelles output was 14Kb. Regardless, as I mentioned in my answer to my self - it was the compiler flags that caused the difference. I changed them to match and got performance back.

Comment: @Zeke Hansell: It's a 70% difference in performance. It is very unlikely that is due to "overhead" or the CLR or anything like that.

Comment: @Jason - I guess it depends on what you mean by "overhead", clearly something is going on to make a difference if there is a 70% difference in performance. Obviously the Pelles compiler is either doing some optimization that Visual C++ is not or the resultant C++ code is just doing a lot more (and taking up more execution cycles) to do exactly the same thing. After all it is the same source code. What sort of things could be causing the Visual C++ to be taking more time?

Comment: As I've mentioned, it was the compiler optimizer flags. The Pelles project had an more aggressive optimization. The issue was not so much the compiler, but configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, been looking up information. What I learned was that the `CFLAGS` options depend on the compiler.

I found the options for MS's `cl` compiler: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

I compared them to the options documented in Pelles C's help file.

Recompiled with these `CFLAGS`:
`$CFLAGS = '-MD -Ot -Ox -W1'`

Performance results after recompiling:

```
> Updating soft selection took 0.679 seconds (12032 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.607 seconds (13470 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.717 seconds (13587 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.613 seconds (13218 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.635 seconds (9964 of 21692 Vertices)
> Updating soft selection took 0.746 seconds (10765 of 21692 Vertices)
```

Voilà! Performance restored - even looks to be slightly faster. :D

Even got rid of a warning about unknown option `-G6` and some other obsolete flag.

Comment: I went back to the update I was working on and compiled it, ~0.5 seconds on average - due to other optimizations I made. Finally the performance I had expected :) I'm a happy panda.

Comment: How did you make pelles output its makefile( or project file )?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't recall. I used a boiler plate project someone gave me to get started.